# TS7051: Parameter has a name but no type. Did you mean 'arg0: T'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-functional-component, react-typescript

Snippet

```
interface Option {
  value: number | string
}

const ControlledOpenSelect = <T extends Option>(
    { options, setOption }: 
    { options: T[], setOption: (T) => void }
    //  ERROR here -------------^-------------
    ) => {

  ...
```

Error msg:

> TS7051: Parameter has a name but no type. Did you mean 'arg0: T'?

Comment: I mean, the error message fixes it for you :). Write `setOption: (arg0: T) => void`.

Comment: @ferikeem Oh, thanks, I didn't recognized it was that simple